# whether the permanent value returned by these methods?

Tags: android

`activity.getPreferences(mode)` and `sharedPreferences.edit()`
Can I do this?

(at some Activity class):

```
//...
private SharedPreferences pref;
private Editor editor;

onCreate() {
    pref = getPreferences(Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = pref.edit();
}

onDestroy() {
    int someSavedInt = pref.getInt("SomeInt", 0);
    editor.putInt("SomeInt", someSavedInt * 2);
}
//...
```

Or always before use should I get value of `pref` and `editor`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create static variable of shared preference too. or can get it each time, both are fine.

Just keep in mind you have to   do `editor.commit();` to save/commit these values always.

Comment: Welcome, If u feel answer solved ur problem, Accept it by licking on right sign on answer.